# Udpate Rollnumber

Tags: c#

SEARCH BUTTON CODE

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TEMP = "3";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        string SearchQuery = ("SELECT * FROM Student_Info WHERE ROLLNUMBER = @ROLLNUMBER ");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SearchQuery, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROLLNUMBER", RollNumberTextBox.Text);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    NameTextBox.Text = sdr["NAME"].ToString();
                    GenderComBoBox.Text = sdr["GENDER"].ToString();
                    AgeTextBox.Text = sdr["AGE"].ToString();
                    DobTimePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["DATEOFBIRTH"].ToString());
                    FeeTextBox.Text = sdr["FEE"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DATA NOT FOUND");
            }

            con.Close();
            sdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

EDIT BUTTON CODE

```
    private void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        string EditQuery = ("UPDATE Student_Info SET ROLLNUMBER = @ROLLNUMBER,NAME = @NAME,GENDER=@GENDER,AGE= @AGE,DATEOFBIRTH=@DATEOFBIRTH,FEE=@FEE WHERE ROLLNUMBER = @ROLLNUMBER ");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(EditQuery, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROLLNUMBER", RollNumberTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", NameTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GENDER", GenderComBoBox.SelectedItem);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AGE", AgeTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEOFBIRTH", DobTimePicker.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FEE", FeeTextBox.Text);

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (a > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DATA UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) ;
        }
    }
```

NOW When search by rollnumber then data show in respectively textbox and combobox

My problem is update ROLLNUMBER SHOW IN Textbox not always but some times. ex. ROLLNUMBER 3 show in Textbox and update ROLLNUMBER 45 How to do

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Do you intend to update the ROLLNUMBER of an existing row? Then the `WHERE` condition must contain the **old** ROLLNUMBER, not the new one.